# multiple collapse items that call one django view function, each should submit a different value

Tags: python, html, django

I have multiple collapse items. all items should call the same django function while submitting a different value each.

[image]

I want to achieve this without using django forms dropdown menu.

what changes should I make to the current HTML code:

HTML:

```
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
            <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                <h6 class="collapse-header">Filter Options:</h6>
                <a class="collapse-item" value='1' href={% url 'show_dashboard' %}>Option1</a>
                <a class="collapse-item" value='2' href={% url 'show_dashboard' %}>Option2</a>
                <a class="collapse-item" value='3' href={% url 'show_dashboard' %}>Option3</a>
                <a class="collapse-item" value='4' href={% url 'show_dashboard' %}>Option4</a>
                <a class="collapse-item" value='5' href={% url 'show_dashboard' %}>Option5</a>
                <a class="collapse-item" value='6' href={% url 'show_dashboard' %}>Option6</a>
                <a class="collapse-item" value='7' href={% url 'show_dashboard' %}>Option7</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Update:
I managed to get it done by using a form:

```
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                    <h6 class="collapse-header">Filter Options:</h6>
                    <form name="modality" action="" id='modality' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option1" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option2" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option3" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option4" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option5" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option6" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option7" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                </div>
            </div>
```

But the layout is now like this:
What can I change in the code to make it look like the first image?

[image]

Comment: Is this included in a form?

Comment: No , it is not included in a form, is it possible to include these items in a form without changing the layout of the image I attached?

Comment: Sure, why not, just don't forget to put different if conditions in the method to distinguish them

Comment: I made it work by adding them to a form, but the layout changed, I edited my question above, please review if possible

Answer (score 0):

Add your form at the outer most part so that it doesn't hinder the CSS & also close the form tag

```
        <form name="modality" action="" id='modality' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                    <h6 class="collapse-header">Filter Options:</h6>
                    
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option1" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option2" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option3" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option4" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option5" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option6" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <input class="collapse-item" name ='modality' type="submit" value="Option7" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And in the backend side, as you have provided different values for each submit button, you can check using `if-else`

```
if request.POST["modality"] == "Options1":
    <option 1 code here>

elif request.POST["modality"] == "Options2":
    <option 1 code here>
..
..
..
..
elif request.POST["modality"] == "Options7":
    <option 1 code here>
```

I hope this solves your question